# Obtains small array by cuting a bigger one in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I'm today working with array. I'm trying to slice a big array which looks like :

```
A = [[a(0;0), a(0;1), ..., a(0;n)],
     [a(1;0), a(1;1), ..., a(1;n)],
     [.....,  ....., ....., .....],
     [a(m;0), ...., ....., a(m;n)],
     [b(m+1;0), b(m+1,1), ..., b(m+1,n)],
     [b(m+2;0), b(m+2,1), ..., b(m+2,n)],
     [.....,  ....., ....., .....],
     [b(m+y;0), b(m+y,1), ..., b(m+y,n)],
     [c(m+y+1;0), c(m+y+1,1), ..., c(m+y+1,n)],
     [c(m+y+2;0), c(m+y+2,1), ..., c(m+y+2,n)],
     [.....,  ....., ....., .....],
     [c(m+2y;0), c(m+2y,1), ..., c(m+2y,n)]]
```

As you can see, there are 3 arrays in my A-array. I'm trying to get them in separated arrays to obtain at the end :

```
A_0 =[[a(0;0), a(0;1), ..., a(0;n)],
     [a(1;0), a(1;1), ..., a(1;n)],
     [.....,  ....., ....., .....],
     [a(m;0), ...., ....., a(m;n)]]

B =  [[b(m+1;0), b(m+1,1), ..., b(m+1,n)],
     [b(m+2;0), b(m+2,1), ..., b(m+2,n)],
     [.....,  ....., ....., .....],
     [b(m+y;0), b(m+y,1), ..., b(m+y,n)]]

C =  [[c(m+y+1;0), c(m+y+1,1), ..., c(m+y+1,n)],
     [c(m+y+2;0), c(m+y+2,1), ..., c(m+y+2,n)],
     [.....,  ....., ....., .....],
     [c(m+2y;0), c(m+2y,1), ..., c(m+2y,n)]]
```

The point is I'm looking for a method which can be used for x smallers arrays to isolate in the bigger one.
I hope my question is cristal clear, and i'm looking forward for some help.
Thanks to everybordy !

Comment: What happened when you tried looking up slicing in the Numpy documentation?

Comment: You can use 'arr = A[y:x]' to cut the elements between y and x in an array and put them into arr. You can generalize that in a for loop I think

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Hello there, i've been reading it for a whole day, but it seems that i can't find any application with my prog.

Comment: @Gaston Hello ! Thanks for the tips. I'm trying to create for-loop to iterate but i think i don't have a good method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is even, then simply chunk it with this:

```py
data = A
m = <your offset>
[data[idx: idx + m] for idx in range(0, len(data), m)]

# example:
data = [["a1"],["a2"],["b1"],["b2"],["c1"],["c2"]]
m = 2
print([data[idx: idx + m] for idx in range(0, len(data), m)])
```

```py
[
    [['a1'], ['a2']],
    [['b1'], ['b2']],
    [['c1'], ['c2']]
]
```

And if you want then split it into variables (or use a dictionary):

```py
A_0, B, C = [data[idx: idx + m] for idx in range(0, len(data), m)]
```

If the data however isn't even, you'll need to find the borders/edges between the data and do something like:

```py
out = []
tmp = []
for idx, item in enumerate(big_array):
    tmp.append(item)
    # last row of current item or first row of the next one
    if item[-1] == something or big_array[idx + 1][0] == something:
        out.append(tmp)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response and your time. I was actually trying your example on my own computer but it seems that it's not printing a value. I got an empty first row. Plus, the point is I don't konw how many variables i'll need for my application. I should create with loop a way to create as many variables as i have small array in the bigger one.

Comment: @NycoElm Can you give some better sample? For the one you provided it works fine afaik as I have in the example.

Comment: Let's say the A array :
A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]

And output :
B = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
C = [[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]

I'll also need to create a loop to create bunch of variables depending on how many smalls arrays are in the big one.

Comment: EDIT : Okay it works well i made a mistake writing idc instead of idx. My bad sorry. I'll try your method plus a loop for my variable and it should be all good. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`numpy.array_split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html#numpy-array-split)? I think this is what you might need here. As from the sample array you provided, it seems that a, b and c are ocurring at multiples of `m` in the main array `A`. So if you split your main array `A` at `m` indices then it would return what you expect.

This can be something similar to:

```py
import numpy as np

...
...


A_0, B, C, *_ = np.array_split(A, m)
```